# Not able to get the TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING

Tags: android

I added this is my manifest file -

```
        <receiver android:name=".ServiceReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
</uses-permission>
```

Then my service class is like this -

```
public class ServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

}

and my PhoneStateListener is -

```
public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    Log.i("telephony-example", "State changed: " + stateName(state));
}

String stateName(int state) {
    switch (state) {
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        Log.d("DEBUG", "***********IDLE********");
        return "Idle";
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
        Log.d("DEBUG", "***********OFFHOOK********");
        return "Off hook";
    case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        Log.d("DEBUG", "***********RINGING********");
        return "Ringing";
    }
    return Integer.toString(state);
}
```

}

I am able to see the IDLE State.

But When I call i dont get the Ringing state. Why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are mixing up two approaches to get phone state. If you use the intent-filter and broadcast receiver, then in the receiver no need to call the TelephonyManager's listen(). Just check the received intent like this :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    String number = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))
    {
        Log.d("MPR", "Its Ringing [" + number + "]");
    }
    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))
    {
        Log.d("MPR", "Its Idle");
    }
    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state))
    {
        Log.d("MPR", "Its OffHook");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks...got the ringing :)
BTW do you know how to make it pause my app when the phone rings and then get back to the app when the phone call is over?

Comment: AFAIK, if your app is running an activity its onPause and onStop will be called in order to get the phone activity in front. If you are running a service I dont' see a reason why you want to pause the work you are doing. Still if you want to use the above method to know when the phone is ringing and then depending on your app logic stop doing the work and resume later but I don't see why would you do that from a service !

Comment: well the problem is that i have a song playing but it does not stop when the phone rings so i asked.

Comment: oh.. ok. Then just use this mechanism and stop the song !

Comment: @nasaa you can also requestAudioFocus and stop song playing that way (when audio focus is lost).