# Incoming call starts a Service

Tags: android

I’d like to start a service by using PHONE_STATE when an incoming call gets to the phone. After that, my service is intended to connect to a remote XMPP server and show any new messages to the user. That’s easy to do but is there a better approach of doing so ?

I appreciate any help or ideas.

Comment: Why launch when a call comes in, as opposed to when hanging up? Are the messages to be displayed within context of the incoming call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036295/not-able-to-get-the-telephonymanager-call-state-ringing) to learn how to get a call back when the phone is ringing. Then you'll just start your service from inside that callback.