# How to detect and manage incoming call (Android)?

Tags: java, android, incoming-call

I want to create an application that can detect incoming calls and start my custom activity after a certain number of beeps (rings), I mean after 2 or 3 or 5 beeps (rings) my `activity` is triggered. How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: im sorry I dont not understand your question. could you re word it or give an example.

Comment: Okay dude , i want to speak clearly , well i want to make a answering machine and i want to when anyone call my phone after 2 or 3 beep my activity will be start , how can do it?

Comment: @Pars - I'm including a very good SO link that should help you with this task. Check it out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036295/not-able-to-get-the-telephonymanager-call-state-ringing.

Comment: You want to block the Calls? Or Just want to start an Activity/Service while Incoming call arrives?

Comment: @Vaibhav Jani start an Activity/Service while Incoming call arrives

Comment: @Pars http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948961/how-to-know-whether-i-am-in-a-call-on-android/5949116#5949116

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can count the number of rings the phone made since the start of the incoming call. There can't be a definitive measure of a single ring because the user can easily change the ringtone to a non-repetitive tune, for example, a song.

What you can do, however, is count the amount of time that passed since the arrival of the call. Set up a `BroadcastReceiver` for `PHONE_STATE` (you will need the corresponding permission in the manifest to receive the event). Once you receive the `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` that came with the `PHONE_STATE`, set an alarm via the `AlarmManager` that will fire a `Service` that checks if `EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK` (broadcast when the call is picked up) has been broadcast after your waiting time. If not, then you can start your answering machine.

I have written [a quick tutorial in my website](http://www.mattquiros.com/blog/2012/10/14/how-to-detect-incoming-calls-in-android/) on how to catch the call's arrival (when the phone rings), when the call is picked up, and when it ends.

Answer (score 4):

My article about detecting incoming and outgoing calls, with the step-by-step instructions: 
[Detecting incoming and outgoing phone calls on Android](http://bitgriff.blogspot.com/2013/01/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-phone.html)

When you detect incoming call, you can start a timer, with interval equal to beepInterval * beepCount. And launch activity on this timer.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Of particular note, please keep in mind what the FAQ says about if the majority of your posts contain links to your website.