# How to change the default android call screen(both outgoing and incoming)

Tags: android

I would like to know how I can add extra fields to the current android calling and recieving screen ? Like the area code of a region or so? I am looking for pointers at to where to start only. Could someone please help me?Just to convince people that this indeed is possible , the link to the app that does just this is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ardent.androidapps.callerinfo.views&hl=en

[image]

Comment: you can't edit this screen (i think, cuz it's execute of an apk that you see), so you must write it again. then it's possible to do that.

Comment: Then how does this application do it(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ardent.androidapps.callerinfo.views&hl=en)?

Comment: ????? what do u mean? it's an application. i said it before , if you wanna change something you must change source. ok! if you had it , it's something. else, you must write it. you can't change an apk.

Comment: I merely trying to ask you how the application achieves what it does? How does it pop an overlay on the existing caller screen. If you install the application you would observe that it shows a small popup on the existing incoming call screen without modifying it? How does it do that. Or is it that they copied the source code for the default incoming android screen and added an extra popup up to it? SOme pointers would be greatly useful since I am kind of stuck now.

Comment: too much question... look, i didn't work in this issue, but i think u must first, find out when the phone ringing, then set your own layout to showing. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036295/not-able-to-get-the-telephonymanager-call-state-ringing) can help you for start. find the ringing state. then search for other things. unfortunately, i can't help you so much. and can't comment all codes here.(this site is Q&A site. i can't help you so much without any code.)

Comment: @DeveloperAndroid: Did you find a solution to your problem? If yes,then please do share

Comment: I used a toast finally.

Comment: @DeveloperAndroid: After tinkering for a while I was able to add a view on top of the dialer app whenever it gets launched(something similar to that in Truecaller).For more see my answer at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701879/popup-window-on-incoming-call-screen-like-truecaller/24377603#24377603