# Running async as a service

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service, android-permissions

I am trying to run as a background task this code.

```
package com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.android.myapplication;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class BackgroundReadTranscriptWorker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    String json_string;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    String results;
    BackgroundReadTranscriptWorker(Context ctx){
        context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://colconnect.eodtranslations.asia/gettranscripts.php";
        if(type.equals("insert")){
            try {
                String tuid = params[1];


                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_num","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(tuid,"UTF-8");

                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                /*InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();



                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
               stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((json_string = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                 stringBuilder.append(json_string+"\n");

                }


                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
               results= stringBuilder.toString().trim();*/
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        if (result.contains("success")){

          //  System.out.println(results);
            //Toast.makeText(context, results,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to get!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

The task of it is to grab data from an online database and display it to a toast. 
I am trying to execute this code once there is an incoming call but it does not seem to execute once there is indeed an incoming call. Is it possible to have this be executed as a service?

this here is my phone state listener

```
 public class CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
               // startService(v);
                //startRecordingService(context);
               // startSTT();
                showToast(context, "Call started. . .");
                String type= "insert";
                BackgroundReadTranscriptWorker brtw = new BackgroundReadTranscriptWorker(MainActivity.this);
                brtw.execute(type,number);



            }
            else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)){
                showToast(context, "Call ended. . .");

                int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
                android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible you can refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036295/not-able-to-get-the-telephonymanager-call-state-ringing

Comment: Do you want to execute the task upon **receiving** the call or after the user **picks** it up ?? If on call receive you want to initiate the task, then try using  `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING`.

Comment: after the user picks up. it does display the toast but does not execute the services nor the methods.

Comment: Did you **debug** to see whether your `AsyncTask` is getting called or not ? As per the code given by you, it looks like it should execute the task. Your condition value is also passed accordingly. I think debugging can help you. As per your `doInBackground`, it looks like some **exception** might be occurring to hamper your flow.